# diff-match-patch alternative for C

Tags: c

I'm searching for a C library wich can apply a patch to a c string.
For example I have such a diff from googles diff-match-patch

```
@@ -63202,16 +63202,18 @@
 1-1%7CZF-L
+DF
 ENKSYS%7C%7C
@@ -63397,24 +63397,26 @@
  -1-1%7CZIMMER
```

Google self does not provide a C version only a C++ one but it doesn't fit my needs for the project, I need a plain C solution.

I see this [library](https://github.com/arrbee/diff-match-patch-c) but it seems its not in development anymore and only can do the diff but I only need the patch part.
Is there something out there?

Comment: You can always wrap the C++ code inside a set of functions that can be callable from C.

Comment: My problem is the C++ version requieres Qt wich I can't use in the project